# Using Foundation Search and Search Server Express simultaneously

Tags: development, search, sharepoint-foundation, search-express

i am using the Sharepoint api to return search results which i am getting with Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Query.KeywordQuery.
On my development machine this is working fine. 
On the Server where Server Express 2010 is installed additionaly, this is not working.
I am getting no results although Foundation Search seems to be configured ok.

Is there a way to debug this scenario? I can not find any problems in the Application Event Log or in the Sharepoint Event log. But i am not sure if Foundation Search is even crawling my content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing Search Server Express effectively replaces Foundation Search and in fact, enhances it.
Check that you have a Service Application created for search and that the service is running. Microsoft TechNet has good information on the subject of configuring Search Server Express:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee808897.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get search results on my site from Search Server Express, so this is working. But my application does not create results. I don't know if Search Server is incompatible with the KeywordQuery method or if there is another problem. What is working for sure is Foundation Search in combination with KeywordQuery on my dev machine. So the ideal solution would be to get foundation search running for my site.

Comment: I think you may have luck if you switch to Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQuery. However, in the long run, you'll need your environments to match. I suggest installing Search Server Express on dev if you can because it adds a whole lot to Foundation and is licensed similarly. In other words, in most cases it shouldn't be an additional cost over Foundation.

Comment: Its is working now with Search Server Express 2010. Except for the assembly reference and the namespace the code stayed the same.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It's always great to see solutions tested and confirmed on this great Q&A site.